# AngularJS - Everything depends on my login service?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

New to Angular here.

I've created a login service, such that when a user logs in, I store things like user name, email, ID, profile picture, etc. within a hash.

Other controllers, can retrieve this information by adding a dependency for this login service, and then accessing the correct property. Example

```
function MyController(loginservice) {
    this.getUsername = function() {
        return loginService.userData.userName;
    }

    this.getUserId = function() {
        return loginService.userData.userId;
    }

    this.getProfilePictureUrl = function() {
        return loginService.userData.profilePictureUrl;
    }
}
```

And this works fine... However pretty much every directive and every component and every page is now depending on the loginservice, because they need that info in some form or another.

I suppose an alternative approach is to make the components themselves agnostic of the loginservice, and simply pass the required data as attributes. E.g.

```
<my-directive username="myController.getUsername()" userId="myController.getUserId()">
</my-directive>

<my-profile picturePath="myControllere.getProfilePicUrl()" username="myController.getUsername()" userId="myController.getUserId()">
</my-directive>
```

However, this seems a bit overkill.

Any thoughts here?

Comment: could those directives pull in `loginservice`?

Comment: Yes, the directives could do that. So you're saying I should just keep the logic within the directives themselves? @DanielA.White

Comment: @Ricky were you able to find a solution that worked for you?

Comment: @JamesGentes: I found a solution where they talk about separating your session storage into a separate service. So you'll have (a) Session storage service and (b) Login service. Then you would inject those into the $rootScope. I'm a bit skeptical of doing so, but am currently researching this. See this link: http://www.jvandemo.com/learn-how-to-make-authentication-in-your-angular-applications-simpler-and-more-consistent/

Comment: @JamesGentes: This problem is, I didn't want to have to inject my sessions/login service into every controller -- whether that be a page-level controller, or within the controller for a directive. Either way, almost all directives and pages will use my session/login services, so I really don't see any harm in injecting into $rootScope

Comment: @Ricky that approach looks ok to me. Using rootScope is ok for something like that, although I don't use $scope at all (Angular v2 moves away from $scope). Rather than building the auth piece, I recommend Satellizer https://github.com/sahat/satellizer, but that assumes you're using Nodejs or something on the back end.

Comment: Thanks @JamesGentes: Suppose I wanted to build the auth piece for the take of making the backend authentic agnostic (e.g. in case I decide to change later down the road), would you say the approach using $rootScope is acceptable? If Angular 2 moves away from using $rootScope, what would be used instead of globally inject into all?

Comment: My first app used $scope heavily. Now with ui-router you can add your globals in a parent and all children inherit them in views and controllers, as I described in my answer. Or, as charlietfl mentioned, using a service injection is the right way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

You are really overcomplicating things by making functions and element attributes for each property of the `userData`.

If you need the userData in controller just assign the whole object once. Then in view you can add the applicable properties needed to display

In controller or directive:

```
this.user = loginService.userData
```

In view:

```
My Name is {{myController.user.userName}}
<img ng-src="{{myController.user.profilePictureUrl}}">
```

Or:

```
<my-directive user="myController.user"></my-directive>
```

As noted above in comments you can easily inject the user service into the directive also and avoid having to create the same scope item in controller and directive attributes and then in directive scope.

---

Additionally none of those getter functions you have would be created in the controller, rather they would be in the service so they would also be made available to other components. The structure shown in question is backwards

For example from your current controller code:

```
this.getUserId = function() {
    return loginService.userData.userId;
}
```

Should really look more like:

```
this.userId = loginService.getUserId();//method defined in service
```

Comment: I second this. You should let the controllers be responsible for retrieving the information they need to populate their views.

Comment: So even if I inject the dependency into the directive, it still means I would have to do this across all my directives -- and possibly even the pages that use the directives, in case they need such login information. Could I get away with injecting this login service into $rootScope then? This way, I don't have to inject it in all of my directives... Thoughts on this? @charlietfl

Comment: In general is not a good idea to store things in rootScope...however something like `user` that does get used globally it wouldn't be the end of the world to store just the user object there... but not api  methods those should stay in service and could set the user in rootScope

Comment: As far as across pages that use directives goes...no, if you inject in directive there wouldn't be any need to put into parent

Comment: Also, many directives don't need isolated scope, and can inherit from parent. Creating isolated scope just for display when isolated instances aren't needed is not necessary as would normally be the case with `user`

Comment: Hmmm. So are you saying that for directives that don't need their own isolated scope, they can just inherit from the parent scope? How would I configure one of these directives? @charlietfl

Comment: by simply not isolating scope in directive...then it is exactly the same as any other part of view

Answer (score 0):

I've got a similar setup. I'd recommend using [ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router) resolutions, which you can then use to resolve dependencies like user data at the parent, then access in child controllers and views.

There are two key points here:

1) To access 'user' data in child views, you can simply reference the object in parent scope.

2) To access 'user' data in child controllers, you can inject the resolve object.

Here's my setup. This is an example of scenario 1 - accessing data from a child view:

```
// the root state with core dependencies for injection in child states
    .state('root', {
        url: "/",
        templateUrl: "components/common/nav/nav.html",
        controller: "NavigationController as nav",
        resolve: {
            user: ['user_service', '$state', '$mixpanel',
                function(user_service, $state, $mixpanel) {
                    return user_service.getProfile()
                        .success(function(response) {

                            if (response.message) {
                                $state.go('logout', { message: String(response.message) });
                            }

                            if (response.key) {
                                $mixpanel.people.set({
                                    "$name": response.profile.name,
                                    "$email": response.profile.email
                                });

                            }
                        })
                        .error(function(response) {
                            $state.go('logout', { message: String(response.message) });
                        });
                }]
            }
        })
```

In my NavigationController, I can define scope to allow child views to access 'user' like so:

```
function NavigationController($auth, user) {

if ($auth.isAuthenticated()) {

        this.user = user.data; // reference 'this' by using 'nav' from 'NavigationController as nav' declaration in the config state - * nav.user is also usable in child views *
}
}
```

Then you specify the 'root' state as the parent, such as:

```
 .state('welcome', {
        parent: "root",
        url: "^/welcome?invite_code",
        templateUrl: "components/common/welcome/welcome.html",
        controller: "WelcomeController as welcome"
    })
```

As for scenario 2, injecting 'user' into a controller, now that the 'welcome' state is a child of the 'root' state, I can inject 'user' into my WelcomeController:

```
function WelcomeController(user) {

var user_profile = user.data;

}
```